# Como puedo hacer una consulta de una tabla por índice compuesto en rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo una tabla:

```
  create_table "contactos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "operadora"
    t.integer  "numero"
    t.string   "nombre"
    t.index ["operadora", "numero"], name: "index_contactos_on_operadora_and_numero", unique: true
  end
```

Y quiero buscar al contacto por operadora y numero.

Algo así como:

```
Contacto.find(index_contactos_on_operadora_and_numero);
```

y su respectiva validación en el modelo, que no tengo la mas mínima idea.

Alguna idea???

De antemano, agradecido con sus respuestas!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías usar [`.find_by`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by):

```
Contacto.find_by(operadora: operadora, numero: numero)
```

Que utilice o no el índice, no es responsabilidad de rails, sino del motor de base de datos que estés usando, ya que solo él determina cual es la manera mas óptima de realizar una consulta. Una forma de ver si lo utiliza o no, es usar un [`.explain`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#running-explain) en consola y ver que te retorna:

```
Contacto.where(operadora: operadora, numero: numero).explain
```

Como interpretar el resultado, [depende del motor que estés usando](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#interpreting-explain), pero ahí te mostraría si está o no usando el índice que creaste. 
De todas formas, por la información que entregas, lo más seguro es que se esté usando dicho índice.

Comment: Excelente amigo, y como puedo validar en el modelo que sea uniquense...

Comment: @rrg1459 en la [documentación de rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) puedes encontrar como hacerlo. Saludos